# Facebook API Maximum execution time of 30 seconds

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the facebook graph PHP sdk - whenever I call the $facebook->api method in a loop I end up getting this error

Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\as\auth\facebook\api\facebook.php on line 631

This is the sample code

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    require 'api/facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => "53095555325553943",
        'secret' => "231801b76124542642553453cbezz",
        "cookie" => true,
        'fileUpload' => true
    ));

    $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

    if($user_id == 0 || $user_id == "")
    {
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'redirect_uri'         => "http://apps.facebook.com/rapid-apps/",
        'scope'      => "email,publish_stream,user_hometown,user_location,user_photos,friends_photos,
                    user_photo_video_tags,friends_photo_video_tags,user_videos,video_upload,friends_videos"));

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$login_url';</script>";
        exit();
    }

    //get profile album
    $albums = $facebook->api("/me/albums");
    $album_id = ""; 
    foreach($albums["data"] as $item){
        if($item["type"] == "profile"){
            $album_id = $item["id"];
            break;
        }
    }

    //set photo atributes
    $full_image_path = realpath("Koala.jpg");
    $args = array('message' => 'Uploaded by 4rapiddev.com');
    $args['image'] = '@' . $full_image_path;

    //upload photo to Facebook
    $data = $facebook->api("/{$album_id}/photos", 'post', $args);
    $pictue = $facebook->api('/'.$data['id']);

    $fb_image_link = $pictue['link']."&makeprofile=1";

    //redirect to uploaded photo url and change profile picture
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$fb_image_link';</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Could you indicate which api call is failing?  You are making multiple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about the api, this is your php setup.
You can use **set_time_limit** within your script(use **set_time_limit(0)** for unlimited execution).
Or change time limit for whole environment in php.ini file changing **max_execution_time** setting

Comment: So this is another question then, not about time execution. Probably you should check for api responses.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `set_time_limit(0)` within facebook.php file (and in base_facebook.php)

Comment: I've tried my way and @Pavel S way. But in my case (i.e. application running in free hosting space) it doesn't work.
Any ideas?